# Google Calendar Api Android: 403 Error

Tags: android, api, oauth, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am having a lot of trouble trying to get Google Calendar Api to work with me. I have searched a lot and tried many solutions which seem to fail.

What I tried:
- Enabling Contacts API
- Google+ API
- Google Calendar API
- Running the App in debug/release mode
- Recreating the SHA1 code many, many times
- Changing the App name

Here's my MainActivity, it's similar to the one in the quickstart but I changed it a bit to create an Event once done.

```
package com.example.roudy.calendarplayground;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{
private GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;

private static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
private static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
private static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS = 1003;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
    getResultsFromApi();
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {

}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {

}

private void getResultsFromApi() {
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        acquireGooglePlayServices();
    } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else if (!isDeviceOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No network connection available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)){
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "This app needs to write to your calendar.",
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
    } else if(!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)){
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "This app needs to read from your calendar.",
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR);
    } else {
        new createEvent(mCredential).execute();
    }

}

private class createEvent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = null;
    private Exception mLastError;
    public createEvent (GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("CalendarPlayground")
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Event event = new Event()
                .setSummary("Tutor Meetting!")
                .setLocation("beirut, Lebanon")
                .setDescription("Some weird description!");

        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2016-08-08T17:00:00");
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("GMT+3");
        event.setStart(start);

        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2016-08-08T18:00:00");
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("GMT+3");
        event.setEnd(end);

        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };

        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);


        String calendarId = "primary";
        try {
           service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            e.printStackTrace();
            cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Task canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mLastError != null) {
            if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) { // not entered
                showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                        ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                .getConnectionStatusCode());
            } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) { // not entered
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } else {

            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Event created !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}

@AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
private void chooseAccount() {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
            this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
        String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        if (accountName != null) {
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            getResultsFromApi();
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }
    } else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This app requires Google Play Services. Please install " +
                        "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch this app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.apply();
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}
private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}

private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
    }
}

private void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
            MainActivity.this,
            connectionStatusCode,
            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
}





}
```

Below is the error I'm getting. I have made sure everything is what it should be before asking this question and I searched for answers everywhere and nothing to seem to have worked. "cancel(true)" is of course triggered but none of the if conditions is entered, btw. ( See code )

```
    W/System.err: {
W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
W/System.err:     "domain" : "usageLimits",
W/System.err:     "message" : "Access Not Configured. Calendar API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
W/System.err:     "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
W/System.err:     "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar/overview?project=608941808256"
W/System.err:   } ],
W/System.err:   "message" : "Access Not Configured. Calendar API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
W/System.err: }
```

[I have tried recreating the SHA1 many, many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL46H.png)

[Package name copy pasted and everything looks the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E0iC.png)

Comment: Have you enabled the Calendar API in the Google API Console?

Comment: "Calendar API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled."  could you have typed the project id incorrectly?

Comment: @user13 it is enabled... I have mentioned htat.

Comment: @DaImTo That's the default project ID. I'm not sure why it's using that. My project ID is not that and I'm also not sure where to put the "Client ID" i got from the Credentials in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error can report the project #, it means you have entered your SHA-1 and your API key properly. It has to be an issue in the Google Dev Console.

Here's what you need to do:

Log in > Library > Google Calendar API

On that screen you should be able to enable this API for all of your API keys. once you click enable, continue to your credentials page.

Create Credentials > Help me choose

Once you are there enter the API you are using and where you are using it. In your case it will be Google Calendar API and Android. Once you enter that, the Dev Console should help you create 0Auth 2.0 credentials so that google users can log in and use the google calendar API in your app. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, if you check the images I have already done that ! Thank you for the info but it seems your steps are already done yet I am unable to get it to work. I have the Client ID and I am trying to use "GoogleAccountCredentials.usingaudience(getApplicationContext(); "audience:server:client_id:" +CLIENT_ID)" but didn't work either, it says "INVALID_AUDIENCE" error